# Dynamic footer text in rst2pdf

Tags: restructuredtext, rst2pdf

I am using rst2pdf to create some reports. Now I would like to add a page footer to the rst source, which content changes within the documents. For instance one of the reports contains some large tables. In this case I would like to have a footer like "you are reading table 1" while rendering the first table. Just before the second table starts in the rst source I would like to change the footer text to "now you are reading table 2".

Is this possible with rst in general or does rst2pdf offer some special features for this purpose?

Setting the footer multiple times in one document does not work:

```
.. footer::
  footer text


some text..

.. raw:: pdf

    PageBreak

Next page text.

.. footer::
   new footer text
```

This is correct behavior if I read the documentation correctly. Maybe text substitution would solve this issue, but I wasn't able to find out how to use it in this case...

Comment: You probably should write your own sphinx extension to generate dynamic footers, instead of forcing the system to do something it is not capable of by default.